# Empty goals list in m2Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

[image]

When I try to add a goal I don't get any goals. Is there any solution or I should manually add them.But in an example I saw it automatically lists all the available goals.

Comment: Any update on this? Martin's suggestion didn't work for me. I have this problem on any Eclipse installations. (Ubuntu/Windows/Juno/Helios)

Comment: Agreed, the given response doesn't resolve the issue on Linux/Juno EE

Comment: Does not work on Juno and Kepler on Mac.

Comment: Also having this problem.  Pretty sure the problem isn't with the POM, as it's downloaded directly from the git repository of a well-known open source project (jackson-databind).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The workaround described in [m2eclipse JIRA](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-2346?focusedCommentId=127820&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_127820) worked for me: In Eclipse, open the view "Maven Repositories" and expand "Global Repositories". Right-click on your mirror of central (or "central" if no mirror defined) and select "Enable Full Index". Right-click again on the repository and select "Rebuild Index". Wait until "Updating indexes" finishes and vanishes from the Eclipse progress indicator in the lower right corner.