# maven Goals list in eclipse using m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am running a simple spring hello world project through maven within eclipse(helios). I have installed m2eclipse plugin.

when i right click on

> myproject>>>>Run As>>>>Run configurations>>>>and press 'select' in
>   front of 'Goals'

it shows empty list with no Goals. why??? i have tried solution given in 
[Empty goals list in m2Eclipse (MAVEN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088929/empty-goals-list-in-m2eclipse-maven) but it did not worked

Actually what i want to do is to compile my project as i do in command line by using

> mvn compiler:compile

plugin.

In eclipse i am able to use clean, resources:resources but i could not compile my project.

**EDIT:**
It is showing error:

> Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE (the
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required). In most cases you can
>   change the location of your Java installation by setting the JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable.

Comment: I found answer at [http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-locate-the-Javac-Compiler-Problem-td ​133804.html](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-locate-the-Javac-Compiler-Problem-td%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B133804.html)

Answer (score 0):

My list is also empty, but if you already know the goal you want to execute you can simply type it. So if you want to compile your project, just type "compile" after "Goals:" and click Run.

Comment: Thanks Fabricio! I solved problem by reading post at `http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-locate-the-Javac-Compiler-Problem-td133804.html`