# Missing Maven goals when using m2e from Eclipse(Juno)

Tags: maven

I am having a problem with selecting Maven goals after a clean install of Eclipse (Juno) and m2Eclipse on a Windows 7 machine. M2Eclipse was installed via the Eclipse marketplace.

I've generated a very simple application via the Eclipse wizards. I have selected the Run as.../Maven build... option from the context menu then clicked on
Select to obtain a list of goals. However, the list is empty.

I then followed the instructions in this post which described my problem exactly:

[Empty maven goals list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088929/empty-goals-list-in-m2eclipse-maven)

Unfortunately this does not work for me: the list is still empty.

If anyone has any ideas as to what else I can check I'd be obliged.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.  Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I'm afraid not herman. I visited the Springsource forum and it seems it may be a long-standing bug. We may have a wait ...

Comment: Hi: here's a link to the bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344997

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the m2e developers, it is supposedly a feature that wasn't implemented fully.  A lot of users are suggesting the button just be removed.  I would just ignore it and enter them manually, pretending the button doesn't exist.

See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344997

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It's a shame as it would have made a nice addition to the interface.

Comment: I think the thought behind it is that it's low priority because we should already know the goals of Maven based on documentation and the UI is just presenting it to us visually.  I agree, however, in that is the whole point of using an IDE such as Eclipse, to save me time from having to type in things manually all of the time without defining a new Run configuration for each goal I want to specify.

Answer (score 5):

That's normal behavior ... just type in the goals you want to run. EX., clean package