# How to obtain APK library from Maven project (github.com/japgolly/svg-android)

Tags: android, maven, svg

I need an APK Android Library from this:

https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android

this project is a fork of the original:

http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

that provide also the APK.

I don't know Maven, I installed the Eclipse plugin, imported the project as Maven project. If I build the project I get no APK.

Any quick solution? Do I need to convert my Android project to a Maven project?

Comment: I solved this particular case (modified svg-android) just importing the .java files into my projects and use them. Still confused in using Maven plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse usually will run up to the `compile` phase of maven. The APK is likely created at the `package` phase. I'd suggest that you run maven build again (using eclipse if you will), and set the goal to the `package` phase.

To do so, click on Run > Run configurations > Maven Build > (locate your run config or create one) > Goals. Then set Goals to `package`

Comment: Can you explain "set the phase to package" please?

Comment: @Seraphim sure, sorry. I tried to make it more clear in the answer

Comment: Thank you. I see no entries in Goals dialog so I'm following that solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088929/empty-goals-list-in-m2eclipse-maven

Comment: @Seraphim you can type in a goal, regardless of whether Eclipse discovers the possible goals or not. And `package` is certainly a valid goal in any maven run